# Finding the mean of a function of a random variable

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution

Suppose that $X$~$exp(\lambda=1/2)$.

I found the pdf of $U=+\sqrt{X}$ to be$f_U(u)=ue^{-(1/2)u^{2}}$.

Now, how do I find the mean of U?

EDIT: I've just noticed that the pdf of U is similar to the normal distribution pdf, which means I'm on the right track. Not sure how to use that information though to work out the mean of U.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} uf_U(u)du$

Comment: You are not on the right track. $U$ can only take non-negative values. This in contrast with a rv with normal distribution.

Comment: @drhab Ok, I see what you mean, but now I am confused since this is the hint given in the question itself: https://i.gyazo.com/ee84fe491e26e7d7ad92eab6038f90ae.png

Comment: The hint tells you that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}z^2f_Z(z)dz=1$. Now draw a conclusion about $\int_{0}^{\infty}z^2f_Z(z)dz$ and compare this with the integral that is to be found to get the mean of $U$, i.e. $\int_0^{\infty} uf_U(u)du$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition:

$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ g \left( x \right) \right] = \int g \left( x \right) {f}_{X} \left( x \right) dx $$

So you could have chosen:

$$ E \left[ +\sqrt{X} \right] = \int +\sqrt{x} {f}_{X} \left( x \right) dx $$

Or

$$ E \left[ U \right] = \int u {f}_{U} \left( u \right) du $$

Both will yield the same result.